# JDBC Mocking KeyHolder

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

Trying Mock method that have KeyHolder. But keyHolder is null. Method is working. Please help. Need to modify test some how.

```
@Autowired
private KeyHolderFactory factory;

@Override
public Integer createRss(String url) throws Exception {
    KeyHolder holder = factory.newKeyHolder();
    try {
        jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
            @Override
            public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(CREATE_RSS, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                ps.setString(1, url);
                return ps;
            }
        }, holder);
    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        throw new Exception("Rss already exist");
    }
    return holder.getKey().intValue();
}
```

This is my test body.Trying to mock keyHolder but it does not work.

```
public class RSSDaoImplTest {

@InjectMocks
private RSSDaoImpl target;

@Mock
private KeyHolder keyHolder;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    this.mockDS = Mockito.mock(DataSource.class);
    this.mockJT = Mockito.mock(JdbcTemplate.class);

    target = new RSSDaoImpl();
    target.setJdbcTemplate(mockDS);
    target.setJdbcTemplate(mockJT);
}

@Test
public void testCreateRss() throws Exception {
    Mockito.when(mockJT.update(Mockito.any(PreparedStatementCreator.class), Mockito.any(KeyHolder.class)))
            .thenReturn(1);
    Mockito.doReturn(1).when(keyHolder).getKey().intValue();
    int actual = target.createRss("test");
    assertEquals(1, actual);
}
```

}

Could not find any solution on stackoverflow. Thank you in advance

Comment: You are mocking keyHolder not the  key, so you need to do something like `when(keyHolder).getKey().thenReturn(mykey);`

Comment: Have you got the solution.. I am also facing the same issue .. Please suggest.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this..?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following code:

```
Mockito.when(keyHolderFactoryMock.newKeyHolder()).thenReturn(keyHolderMock);
Mockito.when(keyHolderMock.getKey()).thenReturn(1);
Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.update(Mockito.any(PreparedStatementCreator.class), Mockito.any(KeyHolder.class))).thenReturn(1);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I left the project and cannot validate if your answer helps.